# How to set default uncheck all items in bootstrap table?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

I follow the properties of bootstrap table from this website: [http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/][1]

The table looks good, however when I load the page for the first time, the checkall items is checked. I want to uncheck it by default.

Here is my init code:

```
var init = function (elmId) {
    try {
        var tbId = "#table-select-controlli_" + elmId;
        var h2Id = "#header_" + elmId;
        var btnId = "#btn-aggiungi_" + elmId;
        var gridId = "#grid-box_" + elmId;
        var langcode = mifid.utils.getLangCode();
        listName = $(gridId + " input")[0].value;

        //loadData();

        $(tbId).bootstrapTable(
        {
            showRefresh: true,
            showColumns: true,
            pagination: true,
            search: true,
            pageList: [10, 25, 50, 100],
            sidePagination: 'server',
            queryParams: 'getparams',
            locale: langcode,
            columns: [{
                field: fieldName.Modulo,
                title: fieldDisplay.Modulo
            }, {
                field: fieldName.Titolo,
                title: fieldDisplay.Titolo
            }, {
                field: fieldName.AmbitoControllo,
                title: fieldDisplay.AmbitoControllo
            }],
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_vti_bin/MIFIDServices/SelectControlliService.svc/Getdata?listName=" + encodeURIComponent(listName) + "&siteurl=" + _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,
            cache: false,
        });
        $(h2Id).text(listName);
        RegisterEvent(tbId);
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you dont accpet now after have accept???'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can uncheck all or just invert the selection. Try :

**uncheck all**

```
$('#your-table.id').bootstrapTable('uncheckAll');
```

**check all**

```
$('#your-table.id').bootstrapTable('checkAll');
```

**invert all**

```
$('#your-table.id').bootstrapTable('checkInvert');
```

**UPDATE**

Ok i have try with inside a `document.reday()`:

```
var tbId = '#table';
$(tbId).bootstrapTable(
{
    showRefresh: true,
    showColumns: true,
    pagination: true,
    search: true,
    pageList: [10, 25, 50, 100],
    sidePagination: 'server',
    queryParams: 'getparams',
    columns: [{
        field: "ddd",
        title: "ff"
    }, {
        field: "dd",
        title: "sds"
    }, {
        field: "ffff",
        title: "ffff"
    }],
    cache: false,
});
$(tbId).bootstrapTable('checkAll');
```

And this work fine.

Comment: it changes my method from "get" to "uncheckAll", get error from server: method not allowed

Comment: Sorry i have make for method call. Please try my update with only "uncheckall"

Comment: Ok i have try and it work fine. Try to place `$('tbId').bootstrapTable('uncheckAll');` inside document ready(). Work fine fo me. Please try my update. If doesent work, have you an error or other?